# Possible to "build world" in FreeBSD without root?

Tags: freebsd, compiling, non-root-user, source

The FreeBSD [jail manpage](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=jail&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%2012.0-RELEASE%20and%20Ports&arch=default&format=html#EXAMPLES) has instructions on building a jail distribution tree:

```
 D=/here/is/the/jail
 cd /usr/src
 mkdir -p $D
 make world DESTDIR=$D
 make distribution DESTDIR=$D
```

Is it possible to do this with a non-root account? Right now, with a regular user account, I get:

```
$ make world DESTDIR=/jails/base/
[Creating objdir /usr/obj/usr/src/amd64.amd64...]
mkdir: /usr/obj/usr: Permission denied
make: "/usr/src/share/mk/auto.obj.mk" line 69: could not use /usr/obj/usr/src/amd64.amd64: .OBJDIR=/usr/src
```

If I'm building into a jails directory, I don't see why root privilege is necessary. Is it possible?

Comment: Your non-root user needs permission to write files to `/usr/obj`.

Comment: @Peschke Yes, I gathered this; it's exactly the error message. Is this all it will need? Or will I have to find out by doing the full build as root? Or is there an option to avoid root? Have you tried this?

Comment: You can override the default build directory with the `MAKEOBJDIRPREFIX` knob. It's probably worth reading the `build(7)` manpage for advice on the best way to do it.